# Ray.io: Could not serialize the argument <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object> for a task or actor __main__.run_inference

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, ray

I have the following function to run Inference using TensorFlow. The script runs without problem, but when I try to use Ray.io to distribute the workload, it shows errors.

```
N_CHANNELS = 3

def load_image_into_numpy_array(image):
    """
    Converts a PIL image into a numpy array (height x width x channels).
    :param image: PIL image
    :return: numpy array
    """
    (width, height) = image.size
    return np.array(image.getdata()) \
        .reshape((height, width, N_CHANNELS)).astype(np.uint8)

@ray.remote
def run_inference(graph, image_np):
    """
    Runs the inference on the given image.
    :param graph: tensorflow graph
    :param image_np: numpy image
    :return: dictionary with detected classes 
             and their corresponding scores and boxes
    """
    output_tensor_dict = {
        DETECTION_BOXES_KEY: DETECTION_BOXES_KEY + TENSOR_SUFFIX,
        DETECTION_SCORES_KEY: DETECTION_SCORES_KEY + TENSOR_SUFFIX,
        DETECTION_CLASSES_KEY: DETECTION_CLASSES_KEY + TENSOR_SUFFIX
    }

    with graph.as_default():
        with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
            input_tensor = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()\
                .get_tensor_by_name(IMAGE_TENSOR_KEY + TENSOR_SUFFIX)
            image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
            input_tensor_dict = {input_tensor: image_np_expanded}
            output_dict = sess.run(output_tensor_dict,
                                   feed_dict=input_tensor_dict)

            return {
                DETECTION_BOXES_KEY: 
                    output_dict[DETECTION_BOXES_KEY][0],
                DETECTION_SCORES_KEY: 
                    output_dict[DETECTION_SCORES_KEY][0],
                DETECTION_CLASSES_KEY: 
                    output_dict[DETECTION_CLASSES_KEY][0].astype(np.int64)
            }

# =====================
# Running the inference
# =====================
tic = time.perf_counter()
print("* Stage 9: Running the inference")
IMAGE_NP_KEY = 'image_np'
RESULTS_KEY = 'results'

file_result_dict = {}

for filename in TEST_IMAGES:
    image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(Image.open(filename))
    
    output_dict = run_inference.remote(graph, image_np)
 
    results = process_output(output_dict[DETECTION_CLASSES_KEY],
                             output_dict[DETECTION_SCORES_KEY],
                             output_dict[DETECTION_BOXES_KEY],
                             category_index)

    file_result_dict[filename] = { IMAGE_NP_KEY: image_np, RESULTS_KEY: results }
toc = time.perf_counter()
print("Stage 9 completed in", round(toc - tic, 2), "seconds")
```

I encountered the following error while sending the function to `@ray.remote`:

```
* Stage 9: Running the inference
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
python/ray/_raylet.pyx in ray._raylet.prepare_args_internal()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/serialization.py in serialize(self, value)
    412         else:
--> 413             return self._serialize_to_msgpack(value)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/serialization.py in _serialize_to_msgpack(self, value)
    390             metadata = ray_constants.OBJECT_METADATA_TYPE_PYTHON
--> 391             pickle5_serialized_object = self._serialize_to_pickle5(
    392                 metadata, python_objects

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/serialization.py in _serialize_to_pickle5(self, metadata, value)
    352             self.get_and_clear_contained_object_refs()
--> 353             raise e
    354         finally:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/serialization.py in _serialize_to_pickle5(self, metadata, value)
    347             self.set_in_band_serialization()
--> 348             inband = pickle.dumps(
    349                 value, protocol=5, buffer_callback=writer.buffer_callback

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py in dumps(obj, protocol, buffer_callback)
     72             )
---> 73             cp.dump(obj)
     74             return file.getvalue()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/cloudpickle/cloudpickle_fast.py in dump(self, obj)
    619         try:
--> 620             return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
    621         except RuntimeError as e:

TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-e130c8b3d1e6> in <module>
     12     image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(Image.open(filename))
     13 
---> 14     output_dict = run_inference.remote(graph, image_np)
     15 
     16     results = process_output(output_dict[DETECTION_CLASSES_KEY],

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/remote_function.py in _remote_proxy(*args, **kwargs)
    155         @wraps(function)
    156         def _remote_proxy(*args, **kwargs):
--> 157             return self._remote(args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    158 
    159         self.remote = _remote_proxy

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/util/tracing/tracing_helper.py in _invocation_remote_span(self, args, kwargs, *_args, **_kwargs)
    301             if kwargs is not None:
    302                 assert "_ray_trace_ctx" not in kwargs
--> 303             return method(self, args, kwargs, *_args, **_kwargs)
    304 
    305         assert "_ray_trace_ctx" not in kwargs

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/remote_function.py in _remote(self, args, kwargs, num_returns, num_cpus, num_gpus, memory, object_store_memory, accelerator_type, resources, max_retries, retry_exceptions, placement_group, placement_group_bundle_index, placement_group_capture_child_tasks, runtime_env, name, scheduling_strategy)
    443             invocation = self._decorator(invocation)
    444 
--> 445         return invocation(args, kwargs)
    446 
    447     def bind(self, *args, **kwargs):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ray/remote_function.py in invocation(args, kwargs)
    419                     not self._is_cross_language
    420                 ), "Cross language remote function cannot be executed locally."
--> 421             object_refs = worker.core_worker.submit_task(
    422                 self._language,
    423                 self._function_descriptor,

python/ray/_raylet.pyx in ray._raylet.CoreWorker.submit_task()

python/ray/_raylet.pyx in ray._raylet.CoreWorker.submit_task()

python/ray/_raylet.pyx in ray._raylet.prepare_args_and_increment_put_refs()

python/ray/_raylet.pyx in ray._raylet.prepare_args_and_increment_put_refs()

python/ray/_raylet.pyx in ray._raylet.prepare_args_internal()

TypeError: Could not serialize the argument <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x7f1c68de2160> for a task or actor __main__.run_inference. Check https://docs.ray.io/en/master/serialization.html#troubleshooting for more information.
```

How can I resolve this serialization issue?

- TensorFlow: 2.9.1
- Python: 3.8.5
- Ray: 1.12.1

2 Ray Computing Nodes:

- CPU: Intel® Xeon® Silver 4210R 13.75M Cache, 2.40 GHz
- RAM: 128GB RAM
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2080 Ti TURBO 11GB (rev. 2.0) x4 (Driver version: 450.156.00)

Comment: The error is probably coming from passing `graph` which is a TensorFlow graph into `run_inference.remote(graph, image_np)`. TensorFlow graphs can't be serialized and passed into remote functions. If you only pass numpy arrays in or other regular Python objects, then it should work fine. Could you try that to confirm? The workaround could be to just pass in numpy arrays and regular Python objects into `run_inference` and then create the TensorFlow graph inside of `run_inference`.

Comment: Yes, it works. I end up putting the whole chunk of codes inside a `def` and assign it to `@ray.remote`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Robert in the above comment,

> The workaround could be to just pass in numpy arrays and regular Python objects into run_inference and then create the TensorFlow graph inside of run_inference